# How to trigger certain function for a particular window size

Tags: jquery

i need to trigger zooming function for a particular window size to make responsive site.Am using *elevatezoom.js* for zooming

```
<img id="zoom_01" src="assets/images/small/image1.png" data-zoom-image="assets/images/large/image1.jpg" class="example-image">
```

Am trying to call the zoom by

```
    var width = $(screen).width();
    var height = $(screen).height();
    if (width >= 980)  {
        $('#zoom_01').elevateZoom();

    }
```

how can i solve this

Comment: Please show some code, and that you've made attempts to solve this on your own.

Comment: Can you show some more code? Where is this code part of? Do you have a `resize`? Where and how did you define `screen`? And what do you get now? Any errors in your console?

Comment: it show an error as 'jquery-1.10.2.min.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'width' in undefined'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var width = window.innerWidth;
var height = window.innerHeight;

if (width >= 980)  {
    $('#zoom_01').elevateZoom();
}
```

Comment: How do you know the `width = $(screen).width()` doesn't already do the same?

Comment: i know it, because he didn't declare `screen`.

Comment: Maybe that is part of the code OP hasn't included in the question.

Comment: Thank u..  this is very help full one

Comment: @putvande if he just didn't included it, he should update his question. Then i could update my answer... i interpreted it like a pseudo code, so i told him the correct js code. and i think i was right... ;-)